# How to reach scope from factory function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ui-grid

I have a ng-grid and its options are as following:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    selectionRowHeaderWidth: 35,
    rowHeight: 35,
    showGridFooter: false,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        {
            name: "",
            field: "fake",
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >' +
            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="!row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.deleteRow($event)">Delete</button>' +
            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="!row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.enterEditMode($event)">Edit</button>' +
            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.saveEdit($event)">Update</button>' +
            '<button value="Edit" ng-if="row.inlineEdit.isEditModeOn" ng-click="row.inlineEdit.cancelEdit($event)">Cancel</button>' +
            '</div>',
            enableCellEdit: false,
            enableFiltering: false,
            enableSorting: false,
            showSortMenu: false,
            enableColumnMenu: false,
            width: "10%"
        },
        {
            name: 'Id',
            visible: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Key',
            enableCellEdit: true,
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><div ng-class="{\'viewr-dirty\' : row.inlineEdit.entity[col.field].isValueChanged }">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div></div>',
            width: "30%"
        },

        {
            name: 'Value',
            enableCellEdit: true,
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><div ng-class="{\'viewr-dirty\' : row.inlineEdit.entity[col.field].isValueChanged }">{{row.entity[col.field]}}</div></div>',
            width: "30%"
        }

    ]
}
```

I am using inline edit so there are buttons in cell. One of these buttons is delete. When I click this button, record is deleted from database. However I want the grid to be refreshed after deleting operation is finished. I call functions from factory:

```
angular.module('ui.grid').factory('InlineEdit', function ($interval, $rootScope, $mdDialog, LocalizationService, AlertDialogFactory) {
function inlineEdit(entity, index, grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
    this.index = index;
    this.entity = {};
    this.isEditModeOn = false;
    this.init(entity);
}

inlineEdit.prototype = {
    init: function (rawEntity) {
        var self = this;

        for (var prop in rawEntity) {
            self.entity[prop] = {
                value: rawEntity[prop],
                isValueChanged: false,
                isSave: false,
                isCancel: false,
                isEdit: false
            }
        }
    },

    deleteRow: function (event) {
        event && event.stopPropagation();
        var self = this;

        self.isEditModeOn = false;

        for (var prop in self.entity) {
            self.entity[prop].isSave = true;
            self.entity[prop].isEdit = false;
        }
        LocalizationService.deleteRow(self.grid.rows[self.index]).then(function (result) {
            if (result.data.IsOk) {
                // CODE HERE...
            }
            else {
                AlertDialogFactory.ShowAlertDialog(result.data.Message, "ERROR");
            }
        });
    },
}
    return inlineEdit;
})
```

if `result.data.IsOk` is true, How can i refresh `gridOptions.data` from factory function? How can i reach to scope from factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution you can broadcast an event from $rootScope.
It will be like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("rowDeleted");
```

And handle that event in place where you have access to $scope.

```
$scope.$on("rowDeleted", deleteHandler);
```

Comment: I've been dealing with this problem for 2 days. I've solved it thanks to you.

Comment: You are welcome. As I see you use the same conditions for ng-if in order to define if 'Edit' and 'Delete' buttons should be rendered or 'Update' and 'Cancel'. It would be better to add some wrapper for those two couples of buttons and use ng-if directive only for those wrappers. In this case every cell will have only 2 ng-if instead of 4. Such approach will improve performance of your grid.